# use of JavaCV along with NetBeans

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

How can I use JavaCV effectively?

It would be highly helpful if any one can help me out with sample codes which explains how to use the ObjectFinder class in JavaCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no problems with running JavaCV with NetBeans recently.

Just be sure to add all essential jar's to project and also platform binnaries (32/64 bit, unix/win etc.). Those runtime libraries are in `javacv-0.6-cppjars.zip`.

http://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list

Comment: when i am trying to run it , following Exception occured.....java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\kites\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp26535394293680\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Comment: unpack `javacv-0.6-cppjars.zip` and you should find a jar for your operating system version like Windows 64bit - add it to project, maybe you are doing something wrong. You can for test purposes put this .dll from this zip in working directory on application run.

Comment: @ Killer_PL ....will you please more specific.... about .dll file